# RDBMS store list of children in father table

Tags: mysql, database-design, rdbms

[image]

If I want to find all the children of `"John"`, i need to run `SELECT * FROM Child where Father_Name = "John"` which searches through the entire `Child` table.

Is there a way to design it such that the `Father` table will contain the list of children so that i can get all children of `"John"` by simply searching for the `"John"` row in the `Father` table?

Comment: Why do you think it searches the entire Child table? It will use an index to locate the children of john an the n acces these rows. But not the entire table.

Comment: Would it still take log(size of Child table) to locate the children?

Comment: If  an index i used, 2 or 3 datablocks from these index will be needed. Maybe the first (and even the second) are already in the cache. then only 0 to 2 datablocks must be read from the disks. There are RDBMs',e.g. Oracle, but maybe not MySql, that can be advised to store related rows of two tables in the same datablock to minimize disk access for such joins.

Answer (score 1):

Your current design is the way relational is supposed to work. Stick with it.

What you are proposing is denormalisation. It can solve some problems but can cause a whole bunch more.

If you really want to do it you'll have to decide how to hold a variable sized, perhaps empty,  array of Child values. JSON or XML are likely to be the least bad options.

Answer (score 0):

You *do* need `INDEX(father_name)` on that table for efficient use, and to avoid a table scan.  Creation of such an `INDEX` is not automatic.

Comment: Is this correct? http://i.imgur.com/Zb4xbrL.png 

Seems like it's automatic when u use MySQL Diagram to model.